# Stack Navigator error: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params.username')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Ever since I started using Stack Navigator with Drawer Navigator, this problem occurred. Right now, I think I am passing the parent in the `navigate` so that it will navigate to the correct screen.

```
  otherUser (username) {
 this.props.navigation.navigate('AppStackNav', { username: username });
```

}

This is how my navigation are setup. I am using Drawer, Stack, and Tab:

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
  Random: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Recent: { screen: RecentScreen },
  Trending: { screen: TrendingScreen },
  AllTime: { screen: AllTimeScreen },
}, {
  tabBarComponent: NavigationComponent,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  lazy: false,
  animationEnabled: true,
  swipeEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    bottomNavigationOptions: {
      labelColor: '#333',
      rippleColor: 'white',
      tabs: {
        Recent: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
          activeLabelColor: '#212121',
        },
        Trending: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#00796B',
        },
        RegisterScreen: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#EEEEEE', // like in the standalone version, this will override the already specified `labelColor` for this tab
          activeLabelColor: '#212121',
          activeIcon: <Icon size={24} color="#212121" name="newsstand" />
        },
        AllTime: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#00796B'
        },
      }
    }
  }
});

const AppStackNav = StackNavigator ({
  OtherUserScreen: {screen: OtherUserScreen},
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  TabNav: {screen: TabNav},
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  RegisterScreen: {screen: RegisterScreen},
  ProfileScreen: {screen: ProfileScreen},
  UserListScreen: {screen:UserListScreen},
  HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen},
  AppStackNav: {screen: AppStackNav},
  OtherTagsScreen: {screen: OtherTagsScreen},
  QuoteMachineScreen: {screen: QuoteMachineScreen},
},
{
    initialRouteName: "TabNav",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  },

);
```

Also, I am still learning in React Native so any tips will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Setting and retrieving state params is correct. But you should navigate to `OtherUserScreen` since it's the target. Now, navigating to `AppStackNav` causes another navigation to the default of that stack and state parameters are omitted.

Comment: @zvona So I just replace `AppStackNav` with `OtherUserScreen` on the props.navigation?